# How to expand the range of a random integer from 1-10 to 1-200

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

Given a function that produces random integers uniformly in range 1 to 10, how to write a function that produces random integers uniformly in range 1 to 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `u()=uniform(1,10)`, you can write your new random variable `

```
v() = 10*(u()-1) + u() + 100*I[u()>5]
```

Note that you need three invocations of the uniform function, third one can be a boolean variable though.  Here I used as an indicator function

```
I[x] = x ? 1 : 0     // if x is true then 1 else 0.
```

Instead of `u()>5`, you can equivalently define `u()%2==0` (u is even).  You can think of creating 200 distinct values as `10 * 10 * 2` which requires the three invocations of the underlying uniform function, even though the third one is only used as binary value.

Here is an `awk` implementation and histogram test

```
 awk 'function u() {return int(1+rand()*10)} 
      BEGIN {srand(); trials=100000;
             for(i=1;i<=trials;i++) v[10*(u()-1)+u()+100*(u()%2)]++; 
             for(k in v) print k, v[k], (v[k]-trials/200)^2}' | sort -k3nr
```

the last column indicates the difference between the ideal distribution, either sum or max value can be used as a fitness value.  There are more complicated tests, chi-square etc. for more sophisticated analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Call the base function 3 times and scale the results.

```
int rand1to200() {
  return ((rand1to10() - 1)*100 + 
     (rand1to10() - 1)*10 + 
     (rand1to10() - 1)*1)%200 + 1;
}
```

Comment: You didn't completelly answer OP's question. Your answer works in this particular case when there is a positive integer `n` for which `10^n` is divisible by `200` (here `n == 3`). But, what if the question says "random number from 1 to 173" for example? Then your algorythm will not uniformly give all numbers from 1 to 173 with equal probability.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE This does answer OP's narrow question of (10,200).  OP's post does not indicate a desire for a general answer. As to if `n` (200) is not a factor of a power of `m` (10), an answer would get more involved.  Yet why stop there? Could use `m.n` with _any_ `int` value -perhaps even 0 and negative.  That solution would be far more involved especially if `m > sqrt(RAND_MAX)` and IMO, would be far more than OP is ready for now.